# SQL - Return value from row above

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table like:

```
Book        ¦Time Out       ¦Time In 
123456789   ¦01/01/2013 ¦07/07/2013
123456788   ¦15/01/2013 ¦20/01/2013
123456788   ¦23/01/2013 ¦30/01/2013
123144563   ¦01/02/2013 ¦18/02/2013
123144563   ¦20/02/2013 ¦NULL
124567892   ¦03/03/2013 ¦10/03/2013
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
Book        ¦Time Out       ¦Time In        ¦Next Time Out
123456789   ¦01/01/2013     ¦07/07/2013     ¦NULL
123456788   ¦15/01/2013     ¦20/01/2013     ¦23/01/2013
123456788   ¦23/01/2013     ¦30/01/2013     ¦NULL
123144563   ¦01/02/2013     ¦18/02/2013     ¦20/02/2013
123144563   ¦20/02/2013     ¦NULL           ¦NULL
124567892   ¦03/03/2013     ¦10/03/2013     ¦NULL
```

Code:

```
SELECT nextout.Book,
       nextout.[Time In] AS NextTimeIn
FROM   BookTable nextout
       JOIN BookTable nextoutsec
         ON nextout.Book = nextoutsec.Book
WHERE  nextout.[Time In] = (SELECT MAX(maxtbl.[Time In])
                            FROM   BookTable maxtbl
                            WHERE  maxtbl.Book = nextout.Book)
```

This returns for the duplicate book id's the same 'Next Time Out'. rather than 1 correct value and 1 null value.

Thank You!

Comment: 2008. Sorry! I tried my best with the formatting haha!

Comment: Not sure if this is correct or not, but could you possible add something like `MAX(maxtbl.[Time In]) <> nextout.[Time In]` to the inner WHERE clause?

Comment: Sweet task for `LEAD` of SQLServer 2012

Comment: Yeah exactly, I wish I had access to 2012. Would make life so much easier for these cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Untested but something like the following should get you started

```
;WITH q as (
  SELECT Book, [Time In], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Book ORDER BY [Time In]) AS rn
  FROM   BookTable
)
SELECT  bt.*, q2.[Time In] AS NextTimeIn
FROM    BookTable bt
        INNER JOIN q q1 ON q1.Book = bt.Book AND ISNULL(q1.[Time In], 0) = ISNULL(bt.[Time In], 0)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN q q2 ON q2.Book = q1.Book AND q2.rn = q1.rn + 1
```

The gist of this is

- `q` adds a row number to each book, ordered by `[Time In]`
- `q2` joins with `q1` to get the next `[Time In]` value.
- `q1` joins with `BookTable` to get all the original values

Comment: Nice solution :) ps. Shouldn't that be `LEFT OUTER JOIN q q2 ON`

Comment: This looks about on the money, as I am using SQL Server 2008 I had to modify the ROW_NUM line to:

ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION By Book ORDER BY [Time In]) as rn

Comment: @Lala - I was writing this from the top of my head. It clearly shows my memory failing :)

Comment: Your memory is still better than mine will ever be. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

By using OUTER APPLY:

```
SELECT BT.*, BT2.TimeOut NextTimeOut
    FROM BookTable BT
    OUTER APPLY (
                 SELECT TOP 1 BT2.TimeOut 
                     FROM BookTable BT2 
                     WHERE BT.Book = BT2.Book AND 
                           BT2.TimeOut >= BT.TimeIn 
                     ORDER BY BT2.TimeOut ASC
                ) BT2
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67ff0/3

I'm not sure of this:

```
BT2.TimeOut >= BT.TimeIn
```

perhaps it should be

```
BT2.TimeOut >= BT.TimeOut
```

and it will probably break if there are multiple `TimeIn`/`TimeOut` in the same day (because you are registering only the date, not the time). If this is a problem, you could add a comparison based on `id` of the row.

Comment: Hi xanatos, thanks for your reply! The time is recorded I just didnt include this in the table. This looks 99% of what I need however the duplicate Books are just showing in the new 'NextTimeOut' column the time that that book went out rather than when that book next went out.

Comment: @Lala Try changing `BT2.TimeOut >= BT.TimeIn` to `BT2.TimeOut > BT.TimeOut`

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67ff0/16)

Has better performance than CTE.

**Query**:

```
select [Book]
       ,[TimeOut]
       ,[TimeIn]
       ,NextTimeOut= case 
        when [TimeOut]= NextTimeOut then Null
             else NextTimeOut
        end 
        from

          (select [Book], [TimeOut], [TimeIn]
                ,(select  
                       max(Timeout) from BookTable B1
                       where B1.Book=B2.Book
                 ) NextTimeOut


          from BookTable B2)a
```

**[Result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67ff0/16/0)**:

```
|      BOOK |    TIMEOUT |     TIMEIN | NEXTTIMEOUT |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 123456789 | 01/01/2013 | 07/07/2013 |      (null) |
| 123456788 | 15/01/2013 | 20/01/2013 |  23/01/2013 |
| 123456788 | 23/01/2013 | 30/01/2013 |      (null) |
| 123144563 | 01/02/2013 | 18/02/2013 |  20/02/2013 |
| 123144563 | 20/02/2013 |     (null) |      (null) |
| 124567892 | 03/03/2013 | 10/03/2013 |      (null) |
```

Comment: This breaks down with 3 books or more. I don't think it's safe to assume that every book will only get checked out once or twice ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a correlated aggregating subquery:

```
SELECT
  this.Book,
  this.[Time Out],
  this.[Time In],
  [Next Time Out] = (
    SELECT MIN(next.[Time Out])
    FROM BookTable next
    WHERE next.Book = this.Book
      AND next.[Time Out] > this.[Time Out]
  )
FROM BookTable this
;
```

This could be considered a variation on [@xanatos's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18124016/297408) but may turn out more lightweight.